# Dynamic Reverse proxy with Apache 2

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

Hope you can help me with this one, I have an apache server configured as a reverse proxy for some domains. They point to and iis server and also have some php sites as virtualhost in the same machine.

For the reverse proxy I did this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName reverseprox1
    ServerAlias site1.domain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://site1.domain.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://site1.iisserver.internald.com/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain site1.iisserver.internald.com site1.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName reverseprox2
    ServerAlias site2.domain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://site2.domain.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://site2.iisserver.internald.com/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain site2.iisserver.internald.com site2.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
...
```

Works fine, but now i need to add about 20 testing sites (with random names, not only site1,site2,site3, etc) pointing to the iis server.
Is there a way to make this dynamic? I.E. It detects the site2 of site2.domain.com and point it to site2.iisserver.internald.com.

I can not use squid.

Here is my try, but failing miserably so far

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default
    ServerAlias  domain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.domain\.com
    ProxyPass / http://%1.domain.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://%1.iisserver.internald.com/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain %1.iisserver.internald.com %1.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with a two liner like:

The 1-21 case.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[  $(( $i < 21 )) != 0 ]]; do
  cat << EOF
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName reverseprox$i
    ServerAlias site$i.domain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://site$i.domain.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://site$i.iisserver.internald.com/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain site$i.iisserver.internald.com site$i.domain.com
  </VirtualHost>
EOF
  i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done
```

The anything - case.

It prints all the records you need to add to your conf file.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Read a file, or query a db somewhere.
for i in  $(cat /path/to/namelist); do
  cat << EOF
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName reverseprox$i
    ServerAlias $i.domain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://$i.domain.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://$i.iisserver.internald.com/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain $i.iisserver.internald.com $i.domain.com
  </VirtualHost>
EOF
done
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The name of the site could be anything (not site[N]) I just put as an example. abc.domain.com, hello.domain.com, etc. thanks for you help

Comment: If you have a (fairly static) list of the "anything", what above still applies. If not this url (http://www.cmdln.org/2008/06/10/dynamic-reverse-proxy-with-apache-mod_rewrite-and-mod_proxy/) may be your uncle.

Comment: Generating a complex config from database contents makes for easy integration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can use re-write rules for this.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p for a description of how to set a rewrite rule to use mod_proxy.